# Using the authorization Tag on Whole site with exclusions

Tags: asp.net, authorization

Hi I'm using the authorization tag to lock down my site to anonymous people. I've put the code below

```
 <system.web>
      <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/webPages/Login.aspx" />
      </authentication>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
```

However now I need to allow anonymous users to access specific other pages (register.aspx etc...) how can I open those pages without undoing the lock on the rest of the site?

Thanks Chris - I've tried this but for some reason it only works on pages in the home folder but nothing deeper. This actually causes problems because it's not even registering the css files because they're off limits

Ah I was using a path like "~/styles" now that I took the "~/" out, its working. 
Thanks allot vcsJones

Comment: if you want to allow a whole directory, then use `<location path="Styles">`, or for a "deeper" file, `<location path="Styles/MyStyleSheet.css">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish by adding [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) elements (outside the system.web element):

```
   <location path="Logon.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
```